# Flutter error "Could not navigate to initial route"

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm getting the following error when starting my Flutter app:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/animals/cats/lolcats"
The following routes were therefore attempted:
 * /
 * /animals
 * /animals/cats
 * /animals/cats/lolcats
This resulted in the following objects:
 * MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>("/", animation: null)
 * MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>("/animals", animation: null)
 * null
 * MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>("/animals/cats/lolcats", animation: null)
One or more of those objects was null, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and
"/" will be used instead.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I have declared the route `/animals/cats/lolcats`:

```
'/animals': (context) => AnimalsScreen(context),
'/animals/dogs': (context) => DogsScreen(context),
'/animals/cats/lolcats': (context) => LolcatsScreen(context),
```

and set my `initialRoute` to

```
initialRoute: '/animals/cats/lolcats',
```

Why am I getting the above error even though the route is declared?

Comment: If the route contains slashes, then it is treated as a "deep link", and before this route is pushed, the routes leading to this one are pushed also. For example, if the route was /a/b/c, then the app would start with the three routes /a, /a/b, and /a/b/c loaded, in that order.

If any part of this process fails to generate routes, then the initialRoute is ignored and Navigator.defaultRouteName is used instead (/).

Comment: so in your case - as in error Issue is - `/animals/cats/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the error logs are quite explicit.

Since you used '/' to divide your routes it's interpreted as "sub-routes".
Actually it is trying to go through these routes one after an other:

```
* /
* /animals
* /animals/cats
* /animals/cats/lolcats
```

And since `/animals/cats` isn't define, t is getting an error and then is coming back to initial route : `/`

If you want to solve this problem rename your routes with underscore like this :
`/animals_cats_lolcats`
So it won't try to get `/animals/cats` which doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks! I would argue that the error logs are too explicit, especially considering the lack of formatting. Something like `Could not navigate to initial route (have you declared all parent routes?)` would be more easy to interpret IMHO.

Comment: Yes :) Actually I was a little too mean about the explicit thing, I agree and your formatting did make sense. Anyway glad to help !!!

Comment: Also: You can name the routes without the leading slash: `'animals'`, `'animals_cats'`, etc.