# "There was no corresponding route" through Flutter web URL

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-web

I am using named routes for navigation in my Flutter Web application. When navigating to the desired route the URL updates but I cannot navigate directly to the route through the URL bar. Every time I try adding a path in the URL it takes me to ".../#/"

When performing a hot reload with an updated URL I get the following error:

```
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/Page_One"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.
```

```
class Start extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Site',
      theme: ThemeData(...),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        "/": (context) => MainPage(),
        "/Page_One": (context) => Page2(0),
        "/Page_Two": (context) => Page2(1),
        "/Page_Three": (context) => Page2(2),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have also tried this with `onGenerateRoute` with no luck.

EDIT2: I am calling these both on a production URL and localhost (ex. `http://localhost:12345/#/Page_Two`. No, `localhost:12345/Page_Two` and `localhost:12345/#Page_Two` do not work either.

Edit3: I am calling `runApp` by `void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: Start()));`

Comment: Is this helped? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556381/flutter-error-could-not-navigate-to-initial-route

Comment: That seems to be for sub-routes, which while helpful unfortunately did not solve this problem.

Comment: Can you add the URL and how you call `runApp`?

Comment: What method do you use to change routes in the application?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I added the info as edits to the main post. 
@YouriLieverdink I am using ```Navigator.pushNamed``` to navigate within the app. That is working fine. I just want to be able to navigate to ```Page2(1)``` when I go to ```.../#/Page_Two```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are returning your `Start` widget in **another** `MaterialApp`.

The first `MaterialApp` widget you return will try to handle the incoming URL.

---

So your structure is as follows:

```
-- entrypoint (runApp)
MaterialApp
  Start -- your widget
    MaterialApp
      // the routes live here
```

The first `MaterialApp` has no routes, which causes the error.

Consequently, the only change you need to make is to transform your structure into this:

```
-- entrypoint (runApp)
Start -- your widget
  MaterialApp
    // the routes live here
```

### Code

Change your `void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: Start()));` to the following:

```dart
void main() => runApp(Start());
```

Comment: Wow, I have been using a very outdated flutter project template and did not even notice that redundancy. This not only fixed this error but also a few issues with other projects using this template. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect solution! I had worked on this bug for a long time. Turned out that I was using a future builder for managing the Firebase.initializeApp() with another MaterialApp widget. Thanks for this @creativecreatorormaybenot

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
class Start extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Site',
      theme: ThemeData(...),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        "/": (context) => MainPage(),
        "/Page_One": (context, {p=0}) => Page2(p),
        "/Page_Two": (context, {p=1}) => Page2(p),
        "/Page_Three": (context, {p=2}) => Page2(p),
      },
    );
  }
}
```